# VBNet Compare Strings

Tags: vb.net

I have 2 textboxes
and I need to compare those 2 strings to get the number of same
letters/characters.
Example:
Hack
Cake

Total same letters/characters = 3 [ C.K.A ]

How can i do that?

Here's my code:

```
    Private Sub FlatButton1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles FlatButton1.Click
    first = FlatTextBox1.Text
    second = FlatTextBox2.Text

    first = first.ToCharArray
    second = second.ToCharArray

    FlatLabel1.Text = result
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Linq [Enumerable.Intersect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460136%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2) method to find the common character from two string.

```
Dim result As Integer = FlatTextBox1.Text.Intersect(FlatTextBox2.Text).Count()
```

If you want to take care of case sensitivity then

```
Dim result As Integer = FlatTextBox1.Text.ToUpper().Intersect(FlatTextBox2.Text.ToUpper()).Count()
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you want to ignore the case of the characters, you could use the following code:

```
Dim chars = (From x In first 
             Where second.Contains(x, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase) 
             Select x.ToUpper()).Distinct()
' If you need the count:
Dim count = chars.Count() 
 ' Concatenate the characters
Dim result = String.Join(", ", chars.Cast(Of String).ToArray())
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you. The code basically loops through the number of characters the 1st string has then compares each to the second. If you're just starting, I recommend you to think of your own ways to solve the problem. After you get how it's done, you can use built-in functions directly, if there is.

```
    Dim first As String = FlatTextBox1.Text
    Dim second As String = FlatTextBox2.Text
    Dim result As String = ""
    For x = 1 To Len(first)
        If UCase(second).Contains(Mid(UCase(first), x, 1)) = True Then result += Mid(first, x, 1)
    Next x
    FlatLabel1.Text = Len(result) & " [" & result & "]"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to count the characters that are contained in both textboxes you could use LINQ's [`Enumerable.Intersect`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460136%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which is efficient since it's using a set internally. However, since you want to compare case-insensitively you need to project uppercase-chars first:

```
Dim text1 = "Hack"
Dim text2 = "Cake"
Dim t1Chars = From chr In text1 Select Char.ToUpper(chr)
Dim t2Chars = From chr In text2 Select Char.ToUpper(chr)
Dim both = t1Chars.Intersect(t2Chars)

Dim count As Int32 = both.Count()            ' --> 3
Dim show As String = String.Join(",", both)  ' --> "A,C,K"
```

Note that this approach will count repeating characters once.